# Requiring an API from another domain

Tags: javascript

I have an api on another domain, it does exist, but for discussion purposes, let us say it is at 'http://www.example.com/api/MyApi.js'

I am trying to require it in my main App:

```
 const MyApi = require('http://www.example.com/api/MyApi.js');

 componentDidMount() {
    MyApi.getAll()
      .then((response) => {
      let data = response.data
   } 
 }
```

MyApi connects to a json file on its local machine.

However, I am receiving the error:

> **Cannot resolve module 'http://www.example.com/api/MyApi.js'**

However can I resolve this?

Many Thanks!

Comment: You can not require module via network

Comment: So how do I get that API in my app to retrieve data. I guess just an internal API calling an external API